# Can this be done by clicking just one button?

Tags: custom-button, c#, user

Basically, I'm creating a user with specific default settings, I need them to have Group access, Queue Memberships, a specific license, etc.. I just want to know if i can do all this by clicking the submit button one time versus clicking about 20 different links to accomplish the same thing. I would like to program this using C# using VisualStudido 2013. Any tips on where i could start would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce has these primary mechanisms to such interfaces.

- Standard Salesforce UI (of course multiple clicks)
- Custom VF Page with Custom Apex (could be one click)
- Interface outside of Salesforce invoking Salesforce [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/)

In your case, you will want to build interface outside of Salesforce, then Metadata API is something you can explore.